# How does string to identifier binding work in python?

Tags: python, argparse

I was using python's argparse library yesterday, and one of it's features caught my eye.  After you create an parser instance, you can add arguments to it by passing a string and some optional values to `add_argument()`.  Then, after a call to `parse_args()` you get a variable back which has attributes named after the strings you passed.  Here's an example:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('layout', help="CSV File containing coordinates and sensor names")
args = parser.parse_args()
layout = csv.reader(open(args.layout)) # now I have the attribute "layout", very cool!
```

So, I'm kind of fascinated by this name binding, but I don't know how it's implemented.  Can anyone explain how this works?  An example would be awesome.

Comment: One of the great things about python "how did they do that?" questions is that you can just crack open the source file and look. Its a great way to hone your skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways of achieving that:

### Using `setattr()` to dynamically set value of attribute

This is what `argparse` is actually doing. Storing action looks like this:

```
class _StoreAction(Action):

    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 dest,
                 nargs=None,
                 const=None,
                 default=None,
                 type=None,
                 choices=None,
                 required=False,
                 help=None,
                 metavar=None):
        if nargs == 0:
            raise ValueError('nargs for store actions must be > 0; if you '
                             'have nothing to store, actions such as store '
                             'true or store const may be more appropriate')
        if const is not None and nargs != OPTIONAL:
            raise ValueError('nargs must be %r to supply const' % OPTIONAL)
        super(_StoreAction, self).__init__(
            option_strings=option_strings,
            dest=dest,
            nargs=nargs,
            const=const,
            default=default,
            type=type,
            choices=choices,
            required=required,
            help=help,
            metavar=metavar)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
```

### Overriding default `__getattribute__()`

For example getting these values from some externally provided dictionary

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, values_dict):
        self.values_dict = values_dict
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        try:
            ## by default trying to access "normal" object's attributes
            return super(Something, self).__getattribute__(name)
        except AttributeError: 
            ## in case that it's not "normal" attribute, taking them from our dict
            value = self.values_dict.get(name)
            if value is None:
                ## it wasn't in the dict, re-raise the AttributeError 
                raise 
            else:
                return value
```

### Fiddling around with `__dict__`

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self, values_dict):
        self.__dict__.update(values_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's implemented via the [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) function.

Basically,

```
namespace.foo = value
```

can also be accomplished by:

```
setattr(namespace,'foo',value)
```

Easy as that.  There's also a `getattr` builtin which gets attributes.